# Why do I have to download a .deb file to update some already installed programs?

Tags: upgrade, updates

For example, say I use Anki. Whenever Anki updates, I have to go to [their website](http://ankisrs.net/), download a .deb, open it in Ubuntu Software Center, and then click "upgrade."

My limited understanding of repositories says that Anki should get updated when I run "apt-get update" and "apt-get upgrade." Why doesn't it? Is there something I can do to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs are only upgraded automatically if you installed them via

```
sudo apt-get install <program>
```

or the Software Center.

If you install if from another source (`.deb`, `.tar.gz`, etc.), you'll need to manage updates yourself.

Sometimes, you can find a PPA for the software which updates as long as the PPA maintainer updates it.